# How to reload the JSON data on every onclick event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code where I import the JSON data into a variable, and then i modify that data:

```
import jsondata1 from '../project.json' assert {type: 'json'};
var jsondata1s = JSON.stringify(jsondata1)
document.getElementById("project-btn").onclick ...
```

The JSON data gets changed on other processes, so everytime that I click on the button I want to re-import the JSON data updated, something that would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("project-btn").onclick onclick = () => {
    //import jsondata1 from '../project.json' assert {type: 'json'};
    var jsondata1s = JSON.stringify(jsondata1)
}
```

So everytime i click on the button the JSON data gets updated, but this JSON line cannot be at a function.

How can I achieve this?

Is there any other way maybe that I can import the JSON data in a line without needing to be at the beginning?

Comment: It’s hard to follow how you’re processing the data and what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I'll try to rebuild the question then, thanks. Rebuilded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import?retiredLocale=de) declaration like that. One solution is to [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the json file when wanted (make a request). Like this:

```
fetch(".../project.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    console.log(json):
    //Do something with json variable
});
```